# Ambiguous string::operator= call for type with implicit conversion to int and string

Tags: c++, string, implicit-conversion, overload-resolution, conversion-operator

Given the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct GenericType{
   operator string(){
      return "Hello World";
   }
   operator int(){
      return 111;
   }
   operator double(){
      return 123.4;
   }
};
int main(){
   int i = GenericType();
   string s = GenericType();
   double d = GenericType();
   cout << i << s << d << endl;
   i = GenericType();
   s = GenericType(); //This is the troublesome line
   d = GenericType();
   cout << i << s << d << endl;
}
```

It compiles on Visual Studio 11, but not clang or gcc.  It is having trouble because it wants to implicitly convert from a `GenericType` to an `int` to a `char` but it also could return a `string` and so there is an ambiguity (`operator=(char)` and `operator=(string)` both match `GenericType`).

The copy constructor is just fine, however.

My question is: How do I resolve this ambiguity without modifying the contents of main?  What do I need to do to modify `GenericType` to handle this situation?

Comment: Implicit conversions are a good source of trouble. Reconsider whether you really want this...

Comment: I do. I am mostly interested in this for curiositys sake at this point.

Comment: You can also use `explicit operator int()` etc in C++11. This prevents mistakes just as well as using a `getType()` function, as the user has to cast explicitly.

Comment: In an earlier version of your comment, you claim that you only want to do this for assignment and initialization and asked whether conversions could be restricted to these two operations. They cannot. That is part of the problem of conversions, they kick in in circumstances that you might not want them to. You also included the alternative `template <typename T> T get();`, well, if you want *assignment* consider `template <typename T> void assignTo( T& )` as that will make the user syntax more friendly (the compiler will infer the type)

Comment: David, I appreciate your concern, I edited my comment after considering exactly what you just tried to clarify.  I feel like you're investing a lot of effort in trying to dismiss a valid question.  What does it matter what the application is to you anyway?  I ask a concise question and I'm looking for a concise answer.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: That is a concise dodge.  Uncovering compiler inconsistency with something which should not be undefined behavior (overload resolution) is enough of a reason for this to be answered correctly.  Determining if it is possible to do across vendors and how will also further my understanding of the language.  In all rights it is a valid question and off-handed comments like yours are simply not appreciated or sought for.

Comment: @M2tM: It is not undefined behavior, it simply fails to compile.  The way to get what you want is (Like David said) to use either named or explicit conversion operators.  I don't know why you are simply discarding what he said, since it _is_ the correct answer.  (I do admit my comment was born of irritation)

Comment: I do not understand why you are irritated. I've neither tried to offend, nor tried to ignore advice. I am legitimately curious and have asked a fine question. If it simply isn't possible to achieve that syntax then it is one thing (I believe there may be a way with a combination of templates and type wrapping though I do not know it), but what I am being told is "don't bother asking" which is quite another. Bullheaded question slamming is worse than trying to do the wrong thing in the first place, and frankly more insulting because it involves talking down to the asker.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: I see you've deleted the original comment that started this chain.  I'm willing to remove my comments if you would like, this whole thing makes less sense with missing comments.

Comment: I think the chain holds well enough without my flippant remark.  The question is good, and Chris and David told you the answer within 20 minutes.  I (wrongly) got irritated when you accused David of "dismissing a valid question", but I have now cooled off.  Basic summary (confirmed by below answers) is that it can't be done.  The workarounds are in David and Chris' comments.

Comment: The problem with your question is that you submit a particular C++ solution (a class with many conversion operators), then ask how to fix it. The technical answer has been provided, and the "how do I fix this" question cannot be answered given a question with a class named `GenericType`: if you explain your design, why you think you need his, maybe we can provide a "fix".

Comment: There would be value in being able to easily pack and unpack values via the access operator into a generic container type which can serialize and read in json values (including strings).  It works for all types other than std::string because of the char assignment operator.  There is no fix for this except an unofficial extension which microsoft has implemented in visual studio due to the wording for ambiguity resolution in the standard. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/743685/std-string-assignment-should-probably-be-ambiguous-and-fail-to-compile-but-is-not#tabs

Comment: Example: jsonDict["age"] = 5; jsonDict["name"] = "Howdy Doody"; std::string name = jsonDict["name"]; int age = jsonDict["age"];  This will actually work, but if you were to use the assignment operator and do std::string name; name = jsonDict["name"]; it breaks.  By returning a "generictype" which can then correctly cast (or throw if it is the wrong type) you can write more graceful json load and save code.  Otherwise you have to name types twice: std::string name = jsonDict.get<std::string>("name");  Hopefully you can see the desire here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that gcc and clang are correct.

There are two `operator=` overloads in play:

```
string& operator=(string const& str); // (1)
string& operator=(char ch);           // (2)
```

Both of these `operator=` overloads require a user-defined conversion from your argument of type `GenericType`.  **(1)** requires the use of the conversion to `string`. **(2)** requires the use of the conversion to `int`, followed by a standard conversion to `char`.

The important thing is that both overloads require a user-defined conversion.  To determine whether one of these conversions is better than the other, we can look to the overload resolution rules, specifically the following rule from C++11 §13.3.3.2/3 (reformatted for clarity):

> User-defined conversion sequence `U1` is a better conversion sequence than another user-defined conversion sequence `U2` if
>
> 1. they contain the same user-defined conversion function or constructor or aggregate initialization and
> 2. the second standard conversion sequence of `U1` is better than the second standard conversion sequence of `U2`.

Note that an *and* joins the two parts of the rule, so both parts must be satisfied.  The first part of the rule is not satisfied:  the two user-defined conversion sequences use different user-defined conversion functions.

Therefore, neither conversion is better, and the call is ambiguous.

[I don't have a good suggestion on how to fix the problem without changing the definition of `main()`.  Implicit conversions are usually not a good idea; they are sometimes very useful, but more frequently they are likely to cause overload ambiguities or other weird overloading behavior.]

There was a gcc bug report in which this problem was described, and resolved as by design:  [compiler incorrectly diagnoses ambigous operator overload.](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14830)

Comment: I'd like to indicate that somehow visual studio manages to treat this properly as well: string val; val = 65; cout << (val == 'A');  I wonder if it's an actual compiler resolution difference.  I suspect you're right that gcc and clang are correct, I guess I'll follow up with a bug with microsoft and see if that's the case.  I was really hoping for some kind of indirection trick to handle the overload properly in assigning directly to an int without needing a cast, but in disallowing implicit conversion if the types don't match precisely.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/743685/std-string-assignment-should-probably-be-ambiguous-and-fail-to-compile-but-is-not#tabs

Comment: Microsoft has had one of their developers confirm this defect.  I think it's a shame personally, I think the standard's definition of overload resolution could probably do a better job resolving this kind of ambiguity personally.  In the case of two call chains involving a user specified cast the one which results in the precise result could easily be considered the better one (over one which requires a further cast amongst pod types).

Answer (score 2):

I believe GCC is wrong. In the book "The C++ Programming Language" by Bjarne Stroustrup, there is a whole chapter devoted to operator overloading. In the section 11.4.1, the first paragraph says this:

"An assignment of a value of type V to an object of class X is legal if there is an assignment operator X::operator=(Z) so that V is Z or there is a unique conversion of V to Z. Initialization is treated equivalently."

In your example, GCC accepts "string s = GenericType();" yet rejects "s = GenericType();", so it is obviously not treating the assignment the same way as the initialization. That was my first clue something is amiss in GCC.

GCC reports 3 candidates for conversion of GenericType to string in the assignment, all in basic_string.h. One is the correct conversion, one it reports is not valid, and the third causes the ambiguity. This is the operator overload in basic_string.h that causes the ambiguity:

```
/**
*  @brief  Set value to string of length 1.
*  @param  c  Source character.
*
*  Assigning to a character makes this string length 1 and
*  (*this)[0] == @a c.
*/
basic_string& operator=(_CharT __c) { 
    this->assign(1, __c); 
    return *this;
}
```

This isn't a valid conversion <strike>because it accepts an operand that doesn't match the type of object that is passed to it. In no place is as assignment to a char attempted, therefore this conversion shouldn't be a candidate at all much less one that causes ambiguity. GCC appears to be mixing up the template type with the operand type in its member.</strike>

EDIT: I wasn't aware that assigning an integer to a string was in fact legal, as an integer can be converted to a char, which can be assigned to a string (although a string can't be initialized to a char!). GenericType defines a conversion to an int, thus making this member a valid candidate. However, I still maintain this is not a valid conversion, the reason being that using this conversion would result in two user defined implicit conversions for the assignment, first from GenericType to int, then from int to string. As stated in the same book 11.4.1, "only one level of user-defined implicit conversion is legal."

Comment: I believe the reason it doesn't fail on construction in GCC is not because of internal inconsistency with the compiler, but because the basic_string class does not have a constructor which takes _CharT (only an assignment operator that does).  I suspect if it did then this would fail on construction as well.

Comment: That would be because initialization of a char to a string is an exception to this rule. Initializing a string with a char is invalid, yet assigning a char to a string is valid, as stated in the same book in section 20.3.7.

Comment: The rvalue being compared is of type string, yet the operand for this overload takes a char. For this to be an acceptable candidate, a char would have to be initialized with the value of a string. Like: char c = string(v). That doesn't make any sense! Though you can assign a char to a string, you can't assign a string to a char, which is the conversion that would be necessary for this candidate. As this conversion is invalid, so should be this candidate, and therefore there should be no ambiguity.

Comment: I've looked up the chapters.  I see what you mean, but GenericType can be implicitly converted to an int, and int can be converted to a char (as a char can be converted to an int).  To clarify, I believe the ambiguity is between the two conversions: 1) string::operator=(static_cast<char>(static_cast<int>(GenericType()))) (the casts are written out explicitly here, but they happen implicitly in gcc and match the string::operator=(char)). 2) string::operator=(static_cast<string>(GenericType())).  Where string::operator=(char) and string::operator=(const string &) are the two contenders.

Comment: If my explanation above is correct then this means there is a compiler discrepancy where Visual Studio recognizes that it takes one more cast to do option 1 than option 2 and so resolves the ambiguity in that way, but gcc and clang do not use that information to resolve the ambiguity.  If that is the case (and I believe that it is) then either one or the other is incorrect (or it may be undefined but I doubt that it is).

Comment: If it's gcc/clang that incorrectly handles the override then the answer is that I've written the above correctly and they need to fix their compiler, if visual studio has the bug then I am interested in a clever/academic work around if one exists, or an explanation of why it is actually impossible (rather than as to why it isn't a good idea.)

Comment: "GenericType can be implicitly converted to an int, and int can be converted to a char" which can then be converted to a string, you are right there. However, at that point we are at 2 user defined implicit conversions (GenericType->int->string). Referring back to 11.4.1 "only 1 level of user-defined implicit conversion is legal", still invalidating this candidate.

Comment: No, there is still only one user-defined conversion in that case.  Remember that the target type is not `string`, it is `char`, because that is the type of the function parameter.  Therefore there is one user-defined conversion (`GenericType` to `int`) followed by one standard conversion (`int` to `char`).  I added to my answer the exact language from C++11 that mandates that the call is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is: How do I resolve this ambiguity without modifying the contents of main?

Create your own class named `string` that doesn't have an ambiguous `operator=` and then don't `using` the `std` one.

Obviously this isn't a very good solution, but it works and `main` doesn't have to change.

I don't think you can get the behavior you want any other way.

Comment: This is accurate, but not as helpful as the question I ultimately awarded bounty to.  Thank you, however, you did provide a correct and reasonable answer.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;
struct GenericType{

   operator string(){
      return "Hello World";
   }
   
   template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t <
                                    std::is_same<T, double>::value ||
                                    std::is_same<T, int>::value>>
   operator T(){
      return 123.4;
   }
};
int main(){
   int i = GenericType();
   string s = GenericType();
   double d = GenericType();
   cout << i << s << d << endl;
   i = GenericType();
   s = GenericType();
   d = GenericType();
   cout << i << s << d << endl;
}
```

And a more general solution. I think you don't need to create operators for each arithmetic type, since implicit conversions will do the trick.

```
// ...

template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t 
    <std::is_arithmetic<T>::value && !std::is_same<T, char>::value>>
operator T() const
{
    return std::stod("123.4");
}

//...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! Actually, this is the only solution that worked for me. I believe, that this is due to the template introducing another level of indirection, right?